# SQL Server : Authorize User not in domain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express, sql-server-authentication

I have notebook with Windows 8 and SQL Server 2014 Express installed.

The authentication mode is set to Mixed Mode (Windows + SQL Server authentication).

I need to create a new `SA` user for my friend in order to let him work on my database.

We are working on a local private LAN (2 notebooks + routed).

How do I have to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: refer [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/338/adding-an-administrator-user-to-sql-server-2008)

Comment: It's not quite clear what your actual problem is. Are you trying to create another user with "SA" as login name or do you have difficulties in granting sysadmin privileges to a newly created login?

Comment: I explain you better: I have an SQL Server Express installed on my PC. I have the SA User. I have created a new SA User for my friend "FUMAZ" with a Password. Actually he can't connect to my server. The "Allow remote connection to this server" is set to True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql server Express you must `allow Remote Connection` to user can login from other computer

[image: How to active allow remote connection]

then add user with sysadmin privilege for each user
note that port **1433 tcp ,1434 udp** and port in the link bellow must be open in firewall
[SQL Server Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)
note that I you have **antivirus** with firewall you must open port in antivirus too

Comment: Hello, this parameters was already set.
He still can't connect.
The error is: 1326

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now it works, the problem was the Firewall and AntiVirus.
This post can help you for troubleshouting the problem.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Thanks

Comment: I say you that it may occurred because antivirus or firewall is close port 1433,1434